# How to cancel an $.ajax request if a previous is running?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this simple piece of code:

```
$(document).on("input", "#addFoodSearch", function(event){
   var search = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({ url: "/ajax/search-food.php", type: 'GET', data: { 'search' : search }, dataType: 'json' }).done(
      function(data){
         if (data[0] == 'success'){
            $('#add-food-area').html(data[1]);
            $('#add-food-area').fadeIn();
         }
      }
   );
});
```

What I want to do is to cancel a previous $.ajax request, if any is running, in case the user types too fast. I need only the latest request to pass, not the whole sequence of them.

How can I do this?

Comment: use client side .abort() but most server language will continue to handle your ajax request because server doesn't know you have aborted it

Comment: Put a delay on the ajax request to only fire when the user stops typing for say, 2 seconds?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Store the jqXHR object in a variable and abort it each time.

```
var jqxhr = {abort: function () {}};
$(document).on("input", "#addFoodSearch", function(event){
    var search = $(this).val();
    jqxhr.abort();
    jqxhr = $.ajax(...
```

Comment: +1, creating an object with an abort method to avoid errors is a nice touch.

Comment: Simplest solution found in the universe.

Answer (score 7):

You'd need to store a reference to the AJAX request in progress, then call the `abort()` method on it;

```
var ajax;

$(document).on("input", "#addFoodSearch", function(event){
   var search = $(this).val();

   if (ajax) {
       ajax.abort();
   }

   ajax = $.ajax({ url: "/ajax/search-food.php", type: 'GET', data: { 'search' : search }, dataType: 'json' }).done(
      function(data){
         if (data[0] == 'success'){
            $('#add-food-area').html(data[1]);
            $('#add-food-area').fadeIn();
         }
      }
   ).always(function () {
       ajax = undefined;
   });
});
```

... although note that cancelling an AJAX request doesn't always prevent the request from being completed on the server.

Comment: What does the ``.always`` part do?

Comment: @RichardRodriguez: See http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/. In our case, it clears the "ajax" variable whether the AJAX request fails or succeeds, so that we don't "abort()" requests that have already completed.