# jquery ajax firing twice when back online

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script made especially for spotty internet connection which allows a form to submit once or multiple times by converting the form data to JSON (using JSON.stringify) and moving it's contents into a hidden `<textarea>` field on submission. For now, let's call this hidden field the `dataCache`.

When the form submits and is processed over to the `dataCache`, a function named `processDataCache()` is immediately called which tried to process/save the data with a jQuery `$.ajax()` call. If successful, the `dataCache` is cleared.  If not, for example we have no internet connection, `setInterval` is called to retry the call to `processDataCache()` several seconds later.

In the meantime, if the form is submitted again, it adds the contents to the `dataCache`, separating any existing contents with a unique delimiter.

Eventually, once an internet connection becomes available again, `processDataCache()` handles the call and `dataCache` is cleared.

This works fine when online with one or mulitple items in the `dataCache`. BUT my current issue is that when the form goes offline and one or multiple items get added to the `dataCache`, `$.ajax()` almost always seems to fire twice when coming back online.  I say *almost* because it happens about 75% of the time, but not every time. Interestingly enough, if I add a `console.log` to the `success` parameter of `$.ajax()`, it only displays once as if it were only called once, but the data gets processed twice regardless.

Following is the code that is having the issue. It includes a batch process as well which makes it a bit more complicated than I outlined which solves POST limits, but the underlying principle is the same as I mentioned above:

```
<textarea id="dataLogCacheFile" style="display:none;"></textarea>

<script>
var maxEventsForBatchProcess = 5; // set to highest amount POST will allow cross-browser, considering each event will likely be around 400 chars (e.g. 5 for ~2000 char limit)
var nRetryAddEventTime = 5000; // every 5 seconds - if batch fails (e.g. no connection), how long to wait until trying again
var nAddNextEventsTime = 1000; // every 1 seconds - once a batch completes, time to wait until next batch begins
var cacheDelim = "##--##"; // delimiter for events in cache, must be unique and be the same as what the nEventProcessURL expects
var processingCache = false;
var nEventProcessURL = "process_cache.php";
var eventProcessRepeater;

function saveEventToCache(xProcess){
    var nNewDataARRAY = $("#MyForm").serializeObject(); // pull in form data
    var nNewData = JSON.stringify(nNewDataARRAY);
    var nDataLogCache = $("#dataLogCacheFile").val(); // pull in existing cache
    var nDataLogCacheARRAY = [];
    if(nDataLogCache){ nDataLogCacheARRAY = nDataLogCache.split(cacheDelim); }
    if(nNewData){ nDataLogCacheARRAY.push(nNewData); } // add new event to cache
    // update cache field
    nDataLogCache = nDataLogCacheARRAY.join(cacheDelim);
    $("#dataLogCacheFile").val(nDataLogCache);
    if(xProcess){ processEventCache(); } // try to process it
    return false;
}

var nRetryCount = 0;
function processEventCache(){
    var nDataLogCache = $("#dataLogCacheFile").val(); // pull in existing cache
    if( nDataLogCache ){
        processingCache = true;
        nDataLogCacheARRAY = nDataLogCache.split(cacheDelim);
        var nEventsToProcessARRAY = [], nEventsToCacheARRAY = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < nDataLogCacheARRAY.length; i++) {
            if(i < maxEventsForBatchProcess){ nEventsToProcessARRAY.push( nDataLogCacheARRAY[i] ); } else { nEventsToCacheARRAY.push( nDataLogCacheARRAY[i] ); }
        }
        if(nEventsToProcessARRAY.length){
            var nEventsToProcess = nEventsToProcessARRAY.join(cacheDelim);
            var cacheProcessAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "POST", url: nEventProcessURL, data: "nEventCache="+nEventsToProcess,  
                error: function(msg,msg2,errorMsg){
                    cacheProcessAjaxRequest.abort();
                    nRetryCount++;
                    if(!eventProcessRepeater){
                        eventProcessRepeater = setInterval(processEventCache,nRetryAddEventTime);
                    }
                },
                success: function(nCurrDateTime) {
                    // update cache field
                    nDataLogCache = nEventsToCacheARRAY.join(cacheDelim);
                    $("#dataLogCacheFile").val(nDataLogCache);
                    // if there are more events to process, keep going, otherwise close up shop
                    if(nDataLogCache){
                        setTimeout(function(){ processEventCache(); },nAddNextEventsTime); // wait a bit before processing next batch of events
                    } else {
                        processingCache = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            processingCache = false;
        }
        // Turn off any additional processing threads if they're no longer needed
        if(!processingCache && eventProcessRepeater){ clearInterval(eventProcessRepeater); eventProcessRepeater = ""; }
    } else {
        processingCache = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a way to solve the issue without actually figuring out what was going on, but oh well, sometimes you just need to move forward.

Following the selected answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751019/how-to-cancel-an-ajax-request-if-a-previous-is-running) I updated my code above to this (just showing the relevant lines):

```
var cacheProcessAjaxRequest = { abort:function(){} };
function processEventCache(){
    ...
    cacheProcessAjaxRequest.abort(); // abort any other pending processing
    cacheProcessAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
        ...
    });
    ...
}
```

I also removed the previous `cacheProcessAjaxRequest.abort();` line under the `error:` parameter.

With this fix in place, the double-processing still happened, but far less often. To take things one step further, I put in a variable to track how many cache-specific processes were running and only allowed a call to `$.ajax()` if that number was zero. These two together seem to solve the issue completely...after about 50 tests, I didn't run into any more double-processing.